# Badges and privileges aren't removed from Achievements after account deletetion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, deleted-accounts, achievements-dialog

I just removed one of my per-site accounts. This means that reputation changes are removed from the Achievements drop down - however badges and privileges I've gained stay there:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is a bug so much as an undocumented and serendipitous feature. After all, you did earn the badge before the account was deleted. The achievements report is designed to show you what you've achieved and it did just that. We never go back and revise the report when circumstances change. If you get an upvote which is later removed (either after an edit or [by the system](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/)) we don't go back and remove the notification.

You situation is a *bit* unusual in that the notification is of a thing that does not exist anymore (and can never exist again, as it turns out). Even so, the mental model you should have of the achievement dropdown should resemble a running log more than a current inventory. It would be more clear, I suppose, if we also showed when achievement were lost at a later time. If you prefer a financial accounting metaphor: it's not like the asset portion of a balance sheet but more like a transaction record that only shows gains.

Comment: That makes sense, except the reputation *does* go... Which makes sense in the way my reps have gone. Maybe keeping all would be good?